# How to save Tensorflow encoder decoder model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml, encoder-decoder

I followed [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb#) about building an encoder-decoder language translation model and built one for my native language.

Now I want to save it, deploy on cloud ML engine and make predictions with HTTP request.

I couldn't find a clear example on how to save this model,

I am new to ML and found [TF save guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) v confusing..

Is there a way to save this model using something like 
[tf.keras.models.save_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)

Comment: Hi @UpaJah, I don't know the way better than provided by [your link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). Some non-trivial models like a encoder-decoder are not presented in keras. So while keras does its job with session for you, in tf you should control it explicitly. [Manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro) (where `Saver` class is explained, your link, too) is not so short but quite good if you have to work with tensorflow. It helps me when I was stucked with tf

Comment: @MikhailStepanov thanks, I guess I will have build model using Tensorlflow.

Comment: Hi, @UpaJah. Have you figured it out? I have the same problem now and looking for a solution. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Create the train saver after opening the session and after the training is done save the model:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     saver = tf.train.Saver()
     # Training of the model
     save_path = saver.save(sess, "logs/encoder_decoder")
     print(f"Model saved in path {save_path}")
```

Comment: I am using eager mode of tensorflow, how the code will work exactly? I think I need to write the code again in Tensorflow graph

Answer (score 0):

You can save a Keras model in Keras's HDF5 format, see:

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

You will want to do something like:

```
import tf.keras
model = tf.keras.Model(blah blah)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

If you migrate to TF 2.0, it's more straightforward to build a model in tf.keras and deploy using the TF SavedModel format. This 2.0 tutorial shows using a pretrained tf.keras model, saving the model in SavedModel format, deploying to the cloud and then doing an HTTP request for a prediction:

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/saved_model

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late but was having the same problem (see [How do I save an encoder-decoder model with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128813/how-do-i-save-an-encoder-decoder-model-with-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment123969990_70128813) for more details) and figured out a solution. It's a little hacky, but it works!

### Step 1 - Saving your model

Save your tokenizer (if applicable). Then individually save the weights of the model you used to train your data (naming your layers helps here).

```
# Save the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# save the weights individually
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()
    if weights != []:
        np.savez(f'{layer.name}.npz', weights)
```

## Step 2 - reloading the weights

You will want to reload the tokenizer (as applicable) then load the weights you just saved. The loaded weights are in an `npz` format so can't be used directly, but the very short documentation will tell you everything you need to know about this file type https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

```
# load the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

# load the weights
w_encoder_embeddings = np.load('encoder_embeddings.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_decoder_embeddings = np.load('decoder_embeddings.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_encoder_lstm = np.load('encoder_lstm.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_decoder_lstm = np.load('decoder_lstm.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_dense = np.load('dense.npz', allow_pickle=True)
```

### Step 3 - Recreate the your training model and apply the weights

You'll want to re-run the code you used to create your model. In my case this was:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name="encoder_inputs")
encoder_embeddings = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, name="encoder_embeddings")(encoder_inputs)

# Encoder lstm
encoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_state=True, name="encoder_lstm")
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embeddings)

# discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name="decoder_inputs")

# target word embeddings
decoder_embeddings = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, name="decoder_embeddings")
training_decoder_embeddings = decoder_embeddings(decoder_inputs)

# decoder lstm
decoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="decoder_lstm")
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(training_decoder_embeddings,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)

decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'), name="dense")
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# While training, model takes input and traget words and outputs target strings
loaded_model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs, name="training_model")
```

Now you can apply your saved weights to these layers! It takes a little bit of investigation which weight goes to which layer, but this is made a lot easier by naming your layers and inspecting your model layers with `model.layers`.

```
# set the weights of the model

loaded_model.layers[2].set_weights(w_encoder_embeddings['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[3].set_weights(w_decoder_embeddings['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[4].set_weights(w_encoder_lstm['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[5].set_weights(w_decoder_lstm['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[6].set_weights(w_dense['arr_0'])
```

### Step 4 - Create the inference model

Finally, you can now create your inference model based on this training model! Again in my case this was:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

# Redefine the decoder model with decoder will be getting below inputs from encoder while in prediction
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
inference_decoder_embeddings = decoder_embeddings(decoder_inputs)

decoder_outputs2, state_h2, state_c2 = decoder_lstm(inference_decoder_embeddings, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)

decoder_states2 = [state_h2, state_c2]
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs2)

# sampling model will take encoder states and decoder_input(seed initially) and output the predictions(french word index) We dont care about decoder_states2
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states2)
```

And voilà! You can now make inferences using the previously trained model!