# How do I save an encoder-decoder model with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have an encoder-decoder model that makes great predictions but I am struggling to save the layers' hidden states so that the model can be reused.

The text below describes every step I took to train, test, save and load my model.

## Imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Input, TimeDistributed, Dense, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

## Training

After preprocessing the data, I trained the encoder-decoder model as shown below.

### Training Model Code

```
embedding_size = 175
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
en_x =  Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True)(encoder_inputs)

# Encoder lstm
encoder = LSTM(512, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(en_x)

# discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))

# target word embeddings
dex =  Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True)
final_dex = dex(decoder_inputs)

# decoder lstm
decoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(final_dex,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)

decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# While training, model takes eng and french words and outputs #translated french word
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# rmsprop is preferred for nlp tasks
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([X_train, X_decoder], y_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=50,
          validation_split=0.1)
```

### Training Model Summary

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, None)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, None)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, None, 175)    499800      input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, None, 175)    499800      input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     [(None, 512), (None, 1409024     embedding[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   [(None, None, 512),  1409024     embedding_1[0][0]                
                                                                 lstm[0][1]                       
                                                                 lstm[0][2]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistribut (None, None, 2856)   1465128     lstm_1[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,282,776
Trainable params: 5,282,776
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

## Inference

After training I created the following inference model (as the training model uses teacher reinforcing and cannot be used to make predictions).

### Inference Model

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

# Redefine the decoder model with decoder will be getting below inputs from encoder while in prediction
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
final_dex2 = dex(decoder_inputs)

decoder_outputs2, state_h2, state_c2 = decoder_lstm(final_dex2, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)

decoder_states2 = [state_h2, state_c2]
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs2)

# sampling model will take encoder states and decoder_input (seed initially) and output the predictions. We don't care about decoder_states2
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states2)
```

Now all I needed was a function that makes predictions (see below), and after some testing found that my model had a 97.2% accuracy on the testing set.

```
def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1))
    
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0] = tokenizer.word_index['<sos>']

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = []
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict(
            [target_seq] + states_value)

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = tokenizer.index_word[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence.append(sampled_char)

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if (sampled_char == '<eos>' or
           len(decoded_sentence) > 6):
            stop_condition = True

       # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
        target_seq[0, 0] = sampled_token_index

        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c]
        
    return decoded_sentence
```

## Saving the Model

I then saved the training model and the two inference models. I also saved the tokeniser I used to preprocess the data.

```
model.save('training_model.h5')
encoder_model.save('encoder_model.h5')
decoder_model.save('decoder_model.h5')

with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

## Loading the Model

This is where I am getting stuck! In order to make predictions I need to load the layers and states: `encoder_inputs`, `encoder_states`, `dex`, `decoder_inputs`, `decoder_lstm` and `decoder_dense`

### Attempt 1

At first I tried simply loading `encoder_model` and `decoder_model` then simply calling `decode_sequence()` but the loaded model had an   accuracy of 0% - clearly the hidden states were not being saved as I expected them.

### Attempt 2

I then attempted to load the layers of the initial training model and then recreating the inference model. Here is what I tried...

```
encoder_inputs = model.layers[0]
_, state_h, state_c = model.layers[4].output
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_inputs = model.layers[1]
decoder_lstm = model.layers[5]
```

Then re-ran the code in the **Inference** section.

This cause the following error...

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: <keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x16b7010a0> (missing previous layer metadata).
```

I am not really sure what to do at this point. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add full working code for model creation along with import statements?

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not say why it didn't work and what you actually tried.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy my apologies, I thought I had added sufficient information. I have updated my question to contain everything I did and everything I tried. Do you mind taking another look at my question? Thanks

Comment: You are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras which is not supported (just look at the error mentioning tf.keras and keras)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for your comment. I fixed the imports, retraining the model and went through the steps detailed above but still received the same error. I have updated my question to reflect this. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution! It is a little hacky, but it works! Here are the steps I took to save and load the trained model.

### Step 1 - Save the tokenizer and the weights each individual layer

```
# Save the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# save the weights individually
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()
    if weights != []:
        np.savez(f'{layer.name}.npz', weights)
```

### Step 2 - Load the tokenizer and the layers

```
# load the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

# load the weights
w_encoder_embeddings = np.load('encoder_embeddings.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_decoder_embeddings = np.load('decoder_embeddings.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_encoder_lstm = np.load('encoder_lstm.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_decoder_lstm = np.load('decoder_lstm.npz', allow_pickle=True)
w_dense = np.load('dense.npz', allow_pickle=True)
```

### Step 3 - Recreate the training model

This is my model (see question for more details):

```
embedding_size = 175
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name="encoder_inputs")
encoder_embeddings = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, name="encoder_embeddings")(encoder_inputs)

# Encoder lstm
encoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_state=True, name="encoder_lstm")
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embeddings)

# discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name="decoder_inputs")

# target word embeddings
decoder_embeddings = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, name="decoder_embeddings")
training_decoder_embeddings = decoder_embeddings(decoder_inputs)

# decoder lstm
decoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="decoder_lstm")
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(training_decoder_embeddings,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)

decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'), name="dense")
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# While training, model takes input and traget words and outputs target strings
loaded_model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs, name="training_model")
```

Now we want to apply our saved weights to the layers in this model

```
# set the weights of the model

loaded_model.layers[2].set_weights(w_encoder_embeddings['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[3].set_weights(w_decoder_embeddings['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[4].set_weights(w_encoder_lstm['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[5].set_weights(w_decoder_lstm['arr_0'])
loaded_model.layers[6].set_weights(w_dense['arr_0'])
```

### Step 4 - Create the inference model

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

# Redefine the decoder model with decoder will be getting below inputs from encoder while in prediction
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(512,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
inference_decoder_embeddings = decoder_embeddings(decoder_inputs)

decoder_outputs2, state_h2, state_c2 = decoder_lstm(inference_decoder_embeddings, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)

decoder_states2 = [state_h2, state_c2]
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs2)

# sampling model will take encoder states and decoder_input(seed initially) and output the predictions(french word index) We dont care about decoder_states2
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states2)
```

And voilà! I can now make inferences using the previously trained model!